Dockerfile vs docker compose, why files content is not being copied in compose
I have a Dockerfile which works if i make a container out of it, but doesnt work completely when i run it via compose yaml file.
so below is the Dockerfile, and i copy a shell.sh from my localmachine to container, all ok in this case.
Dockerfile:
FROM alpine:latest
LABEL maintainer="hasham1983@yahoo.com"
RUN mkdir -p /tmp/hasham
COPY ./shell.sh /tmp/hasham/
RUN chmod 775 /tmp/hasham/shell.sh
RUN echo '*/1  *  *  *  *    /tmp/hasham/shell.sh' > /etc/crontabs/root
CMD crond && sleep infinite



However the problem is whenever I run this dockerfile as a part of docker compose, the shell script created on the container is empty. the filename is there in the container but with no contents. I dont understand why is this happening only when running through compose. I tried with another simple text file also and got the same problem, file is created but is with zero size and no contents.
please can someone tell me what am i doing wrong?
below is the yaml file im using and it is referencing the above Dockerfile for container generation.
test.yaml
services:
    my_app:
        container_name: myapp
        build:
            dockerfile: ./alpine.Dockerfile
        networks:
            - mynetwork
networks:
    mynetwork:
        name: mynetwork
        driver: bridge


please help !
thanks
H
dont think its anything to do with permissions?
docker build works fine (create image and then container)
docker compose doesnt work fine, i get empty /tmp/hasham/shell.sh (composing using the above dockerfile)
docker compose --project-name my_project -f test.yaml up -d

How are you verifying the file content?  For example, if you docker run --rm your-image cat /etc/crontabs/root, is it there in a non-Compose context?  Please [edit] the question to fix the formatting issues: you've lost the indentation in your Compose file, which is often significant, but there are also a couple of stray backslashes, and in particular echo \> filename will print out a > rather than redirect to a file.

hi..oh yes i noticed the formatting has gone so wrong while copy pasting.
reagrding how am i checking the file content, yes i  can cat the shell.sh file on my local vm and content is there, but once the container is up and running, i go into the container and cat the file and its empty.

I find it odd that you haven't specified the context of the build in your docker-compose file, may be related but I don't know for sure

resolved.
so whenever I was running the compose command, it was not making a new image but was using an old image which was created when i was testing, and probably during that very first build that empty shell.sh was put into the image. on every subsequent run of compose up and compose down, it was just creating and deleting the containers.
i had to delete the image and then run compose which created a new correct image and now everything is fine.

You can force docker-compose to rebuild the image using the --build option of the up subcommand, described here.
docker compose --project-name my_project -f test.yaml up --build -d

A better option is to force a full rebuild with the build subcommand: docker compose -f test.yaml build --no-cache. That way you're guaranteed a fresh image, and no cached layers will be used.

It is only a better option if you want to invalidate the cache which is usually not needed. The build will be very long for just one file that has been changed.
